# Migrating a servlet from Tomcat to Lighttpd

Tags: java, class, tomcat, migration, lighttpd

I have a locally hosted (Tomcat 7) website. In this project I have a servlet which is working quite well (http://localhost:8080/so/hello).

When trying to migrate this website (including the servlet) to a Debian environment I can see the index and static HTML pages fine - however the servlet now just times out (this from Chrome) - Error 118 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT): The operation timed out.

There must be a setup option in Lighttpd that I'm missing.

Comment: Lighttpd does not appear to be a servlet container, but a web server.

Comment: [This](http://johannburkard.de/blog/www/lighttpd-and-jee-application-servers-integrating-jsp-and-servlets.html) can be of help .

Comment: How exactly did you configure Tomcat and Lighttpd on your Debian machine? Did you deploy your application into Tomcat and put Lighttpd in front of it?

Comment: @ NINCOMPOOP  take care,this blog has JS-CoinMiner atm.

Answer (score 0):

Update: lighttpd 1.4.59 includes [lighttpd mod_ajp13](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_ModAJP13)